# How to develop knowledge for VBA

Tags: vba, excel

From the basic documentation easily found through the applications (Help in Excel, for example), one can get a basic understanding and start to code.

There are also multiple online resources (such as the WiseOwl tutorials) that help in improving knowledge and understanding of the VBA language.

Even with this plethora of tools, it can still be complicated for someone, especially a beginner or intermediary user, to really understand how the code works, its inner functioning and how to approach certain problems with existing knowledge.

**Question:** What do you think is the best method to develop the understanding of VBA for this kind of user? How to better "think" in the programming language, being more effective and efficient at coding? What are the best sort of exercises one could do to improve programming skills (in VBA and potentially in other programming languages)?

**Obs1:** Albeit this question seems generic it can, surely, be of use for people starting at VBA. It would be useful to have this thread with a compiled range of tools and opinions on how to improve.

**Obs2:** Please let me know if this is not the right place to post a question like this, and I will immediately delete it and post in the correct place.

Comment: It's not right place, but I can't tell what would be the best or the correct one. I remember asking something very similar in some of the book related sites, but got closed as it was not directly related to books. So I don't know...

Comment: @HanSoalone I tried finding something similar already done, and I know people are going to downvote this, but I think it was a valid try. Still I don't know where to post it.

Comment: No real short cut. Get a book and read it. Repeat. Write lots of code while you are at it. Subscribe to the `excel-vba` tag and read the posts. Try to answer some of the easier ones. Move on to harder ones.

Comment: @JohnColeman You are absolutely right. Practice leads to development. My intent in this post was just to gather all suggestions for tools and resources in that journey.

Comment: There really isn't much of a short cuts but read and code. I learned VBA after I already had done some coding in Basic and C earlier years. What I think is the most important is some goal or program with real use that you work on, that teaches a lot more than just learning simple functions and methods without context.

Comment: @HanSoalone That is exactly what I think about books and rigid documentation. They teach how to do stuff, but they don't explain the nuances in coding interpretation, which I think is what separates the guy learning to code from the guy with real coding understanding.

Comment: If you want actual book suggestions: I first learned VBA by reading in order (earlier editions of) Excel VBA for Dummies and then Excel Power Programming, both by John Walkenbach (whose spreadsheet page is worth a look)

Comment: I read the same book as John, and at the same time worked on this warehouse management tool in VBA. It wasn't anything fancy, but very much simple tool to analyze what came in and when and where it was then shipped. Amounts and dates and such. I think something like that is potentially very good example as it requires nothing too hard for a beginner but still uses many different functionalities of VBA.

Comment: @JohnColeman Do you care to write those as an answer? I think it might be useful for people looking for this kind of information. Btw I personally used Excel 2007 VBA Programmer’s Reference (Green, Bullen, Bovey and Alexander).

Comment: @HanSoalone Indeed, if I had more knowledge, I would create some basic templates for people to play around and put them here. I will surely do it as soon as I develop enough.

Comment: @DGMS89 I voted to close the question as primarily opinion based (since, it is) so wouldn't want to answer it beyond the comments. I have the Green-Bullen et. al book and think it excellent, though that is more for after you get a certain amount of expertise.

Comment: @JohnColeman No problem, would you mind if I add your suggestions to posteriorly write a complete answer, with everything I can find? ANd about the book, it was suggested to me, and I used it to the best of my abilities, but it is sometimes very complicated for me.

Comment: I know my answer is rather simple, but it is what has worked for me. I have gone from complete VBA noob to fairly well accomplished over the last six months simply by solving problems that no one else could. I started with automating basic tasks, and when I mastered that I kept pushing. I am still learning new things and new ways to overcome obstacles, and I intend to keep doing so. While the standard tutorials have helped a lot in this process I have also (surprisingly) learned a lot by learning about other languages and how their processes work (and differ from VBA). TLDR: Learn by doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my experience, best way to learn VBA coding is to practice, specially looking at other's people macros and excel files, since they provide real examples that can be very enlightening. 
other way of improving VBA coding is to be very active on stackoverflow, since we deal with a very wide range of questions, regardless of their difficulty or it's specificity.
"practice makes the master" said the wise man.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Precisely. Practicing by actively coding helped me improve a lot, but I still can't get a grasp on how to "think" in the language. I compare myself to other people I see coding, and they already have some very deep understanding on how to approach the problems. I know this come with time, but having more resources towards achieving it would always be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best tool for learning about VBA code in Excel is to use the "record macro" functionality.

Start the recording of a new macro, do whatever you want in Excel, stop the macro and look at the code Excel has generated. You can learn a lot from this.

Example: http://www.excelfunctions.net/Record-A-Macro.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed the macro recorder is the best way to start.  But to develop the insight on how to approach coding in a more efficient manner is a much more profound discussion, in my opinion, of course.

Comment: Indeed, however the macro recorder usually makes good use of VBA functionnalities. It's not like a documentation for sure but it is very handy if you want to develop quickly

Comment: You are absolutely right. In my limited knowledge of its usage, I think the recorder does not teach how to "think" in the language. But again, that is just my opinion, the more suggestions I can gather in this post, the more complete and useful it will be.

Comment: Sorry, but the macro recorder "write" horrible code. It can occasionally be useful to track something down in the object model, but it has roughly 0 utility in learning the language.

Comment: @Comintern can you share an example?

Comment: Sure.  [Here are (currently) 364 of them](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+recorded+macro+error).  The broader issue is that they have zero flow control and don't separate UI concerns from logic concerns.  See [this Documentation topic](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate#t=201702231503242734324) along with more or less everything else under "VBA Best Practices".

Comment: @Comintern There is only one post with the recorder in your Best Practices link and it is basically saying you should avoid using `.Select()`. I am not saying you should use the macro record to create a whole application or that it is flawless, but it gives you a good idea of the functionnalities at hand

Comment: I could write a book on why the code generated by the macro recorder is bad. The point is that it isn't going to teach you anything meaningful about how to program VBA other than show you what objects and properties Excel uses when you perform UI. The sheer bulk of questions on SO that arise from the `.Activate` - `.Select` anti-pattern is in and of itself a stellar reason to learn by *writing* code rather than looking at recorded "code".